# Повторяющийся союз И в предложении. Когда ставится запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

В предложении

*В лесу можно встретить и медведя и волка*

нужна ли запятая?

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, нужна. Повторяющееся же!

Кроме устойчивых сочетаний ([и днём и ночью](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%20291116), [и зимой и летом](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%20292829)).

Пояснение справочной службы русского языка:

> *И день и ночь* – устойчивый оборот со значением 'всегда, постоянно', поэтому запятая в нем не ставится. Перестановка слов разрушает
>   фразеологизм, что делает возможным постановку запятой.